# Inner join con campos nulos

Tags: sql-server, join, subconsultas, inner

Estoy trabajando en rediseñar la manera en la que esta particionada una tabla, por lo que al momento tengo dos tablas con el mismo esquema.

Dentro de mis validaciones pretendo demostrar mediante un inner join que los registros se encuentran de la misma manera en ambas tablas, esto a raíz que en otros proceso de insert algunos valores los redondea cuando son tipo decimal, float, etc.

El esquema de las tablas es el siguiente

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PerformanceSummary](
    [CountryName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [RegionName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [CustomerName] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ProviderName] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Dia] [datetime] NULL,
    [CallsNumber] [float] NULL,
    [Charge] [float] NULL,
    [ChargeMinutes] [float] NULL,
    [Cost] [float] NULL,
    [CostMinutes] [float] NULL,
    [ACD] [float] NULL,
    [ASR] [float] NULL,
    [PDD] [float] NULL,
    [AAR] [float] NULL,
    [PSC] [float] NULL,
    [IsBillable] [int] NULL,
    [IsFailure] [int] NULL,
    [EsLatam] [bit] NULL,
    [Segmento] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Subsegmento] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [CustomerBillingGroup] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [CustomerTrafficDesc] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [ProviderTrafficDesc] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [AccountManager] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [CustomerSLBR] [int] NULL,
    [ProviderAccountManager] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [ProviderSLBR] [int] NULL,
    [TipoTrafico] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ValorSemanaLaboral] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [ValorSemana] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [DayAndHour] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Clasificacion] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [GeographicZone] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [IsMerged] [tinyint] NULL,
    [Product] [varchar](55) NULL)
```

Entiendo que usualmente no se utilizan campos que puedan contener valores nulos dentro de un inner join pero por la naturaleza de las tablas solo un campo esta definido como  NOT NULL || DayAndHour pero no estoy logrando hacer el join correctamente porque hay varios registros con el mismo valor en DayAndHour.

Al ejecutar esta consulta obtengo el error:

```sql
SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS bigint) AS Total
FROM PerformanceSummary PS
INNER JOIN PerformanceSummaryOLD PSO ON PS.DayAndHour = PSO.DayAndHour;
```

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int
```

Por lo que trato de hacer el inner join con una subconsulta pero no logro hacer el match
1- Al realizar un SELECT COUNT a cada tabla obtengo 40 784 646 regitros

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PerformanceSummaryOLD
```

2- Al hacer el INNER JOIN obtengo 37 807 404 registros

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT DayAndHour
    FROM PerformanceSummary
) AS PS
INNER JOIN PerformanceSummaryOLD PSO ON PS.DayAndHour = PSO.DayAndHour;
```

Me pueden asesorar sobre si hay alguna manera en la que pueda trabajarse el join?`

Se que es necesario mejorar el schema de la tabla para evitar este tipo de situaciones pero  primero necesito validar la información que ya existe.

Comment: La tabla no tiene una clave primaria??? si es asi, porque hacer un join, en lugar de hacer un not in por la clave?

Comment: @gbianchi no tiene llave primaria

Comment: si hay varios registros con el mismo valor en DayAndHour, que esperas que haga el join? no entiendo... no entiendo tu intencion.. si es ver que estan todos los registros iguales, por lo que plantes, no va a salir ocn un query...

Comment: Al no contar con un identificador (sea único o compuesto), lo único que te queda es decir que 2 registros serán iguales si TODOS los campos son iguales, pero esto puede ser falso y dependerá de la lógica que exista en el sistema. Por otro lado creo que debes analizar los datos, puede que los campos estén declarados como "nulleables" pero apostaría que en muchos de ellos nunca se da el caso

Comment: La pregunta más importante aquí es, ¿cuál es el criterio para determinar que un registro de la tabla 1 es _match_ de un registro de la tabla 2? Si te tomas el tiempo de explicarlo en lenguaje coloquial en la pregunta, y me dejas una mención, con gusto publico una respuesta si veo como expresarlo en SQL. Mientras eso no esté bien definido, me temo que nadie pueda ayudarte a construir la consulta.

Comment: Entendí mal o estas intentando validar que todas las filas de una tabla se encuentren en la otra?

Comment: Leyendo tu consulta de nuevo, veo que el campo DayAndHour es de tipo DateTime en una, pero, de qué tipo es en la otra? y, ¿por qué haces un cast del count()?

Comment: @jachguate el cast del count lo estaba haciendo al inicio de mi revision, me estaba confundiendo al creer que no podia imprimir el total de registros pero es mas bien porque hay muchos campos en DayAndHour que tienen el mismo valor

Comment: @PatricioMoracho , es correcto. Estoy buscando validar que las filas de una tabla se encuentran en la otra de la misma manera

Comment: @Caro, pero no me respondes sobre los tipos de datos de los campos DayAndHour en ambas tablas. Sospecho que son distintos, por eso la pregunta.

Comment: @jachguate El tipo de dato de DayAndHour para ambas tablas es DATETIME. De hecho, solo cambia el nombre de la tablas pero el esquema es igual.

Comment: Reflexionando sobre este tema, me pregunto si no estamos ante un [problema xy](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3361/21). Quizás sería mejor que nos cuentes cuál es el problema real que estás enfrentando, antes de contarnos como lo estás intentando solucionar. Quizás por allí pueda surgir una solución.

Answer (score 0):

Si tuvieras un PK, y asumiendo que los datos de una misma fila no cambian,  sería más sencillo ya que buscaríamos filas que no estén contenidas en las dos tablas, pero al no tener PK hay que hacer un poco de "malabares".

Imaginemos algo como esto:

```
create table Prueba (
  a    int,
  b    varchar(15),
  c    datetime
);

create table PruebaOLD (
  a    int,
  b    varchar(15),
  c    datetime
);

insert into Prueba(a, b, c) values (2, 'xx', '2024-03-22');
insert into Prueba(a, b, c) values (1, 'xx', '2024-03-20');
insert into Prueba(a, b, c) values (3, null, '2024-03-20');

insert into PruebaOLD(a, b, c) values (1, 'xx', '2024-03-20');
insert into PruebaOLD(a, b, c) values (1, 'yy', '2024-03-20');
insert into PruebaOLD(a, b, c) values (3, null, '2024-03-20');
```

Para obtener las filas de `Prueba` no existentes en `PruebaOLD` habría que hacer un `left join` relacionando todas las columnas, y además contemplar el caso en el que ambas sean `NULL` ya que la comparación por igualdad no funciona con valores `NULL`, básicamente algo así:

```
select p1.*
       from prueba p1
       left join pruebaOLD p2
            on (p1.a = p2.a or (p1.a is null and p2.a is null))
            and (p1.b = p2.b or (p1.b is null and p2.b is null))
            and (p1.c = p2.c or (p1.c is null and p2.c is null))
      where p2.a is null
```

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | xx | 2024-03-22 00:00:00.000 |

En el `where` hay que seleccionar una columna de la que sepamos no contiene valores nulos. esto nos recupera las filas de `prueba` que no existen en `pruebaOLD` si queremos obtener lo inverso hay que invertir las tablas en el `select` y eventualmente hacer un `union`. Este tipo de consulta es muy poco performante, no hay índices que valgan, la comparación debe hacerse fila por fila.

Hay otra forma un poco más compacta que te ofrece **SQL Server** que es mediante la clausula [`EXCEPT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016)

```
select 'Prueba' as 'De', * from Prueba
EXCEPT
select 'Prueba', * from PruebaOld
UNION
select 'PruebaOLD', * from PruebaOLD
EXCEPT
select 'PruebaOLD', * from Prueba
```

| De | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Prueba | 2 | xx | 2024-03-22 00:00:00.000 |
| PruebaOLD | 1 | yy | 2024-03-20 00:00:00.000 |

Esto lo que nos permite obtener son las filas distintas de cada tabla.